# Laravel same validator

Tags: php, laravel

My case is for change password option. I already have current password in object `$pass`. I want to validate this `$pass` against textbox form input current_password to proceed to create a new password for the user. How to validate with same validator. Sorry I'm new to laravel.

```
$rules = array('password_current' => "required|same:$pass");
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

since `same:` used to ensure that the value of current field is the same as **another field** defined by the rule parameter (**not object**). so you can't use this function take a look this example code below.

```
$data = Input::all();
$rules = array(
    'email' => 'required|same:old_email',
);
```

the above code will check if current email field is same as old_email field.
so i think you can you simple if else

in your handle controller function assume

```
public function handleCheck(){

$current_password = Input::get('current_password');
$pass = //your object pass;
if($current_password == $pass){
  // password correct , show change password form
}else{
 //  password incorrect , show error
}
}
```

let me know if it works. see [Laravel Validation same](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-same)

Comment: Actually,my case is different. This one is for change password option. I already have current password in object $pass. I want to validate this $pass against textbox input current_password to proceed to create a new password for the user.

Comment: let me know if here is what you want. so user input current password in current_password text field , then user click Change password button which will create new password for the user ( show create new password form ) ? am i right ?

Comment: Yes..I already have old password in $pass variable. I want to validate this $pass against current_password value while clicking change password button.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was not aware of it. It helped me to solve it.

Comment: Is there any validator with similar functionality?

Answer (score 1):

If you have password stored in `$pass` already just inject $pass in the request and use its field instead for e.g.

```
$request->request->add(['password_old' => $pass]);
```

Then, you can validate it like

```
$rules = array('password_current' => "required|same:password_old");
```